# I want to close/hide this div when user clicks Yes

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to close/hide this div once a user clicks on Yes. It does it when No is clicked and I can't figure out how to do it when Yes is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
var sg_div = document.createElement("div"); sg_div.innerHTML = "<h2>Welcome!</h2>Your opinion is important to us. After your visit, would you be willing to answer a few questions?
<p><center><a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" 
onclick=\"window.open(this.href,'_self');window.open('#','_blank');\">
<button>Yes</button></a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('sg-popup').style.display = 'none';return false;\">
<button>No, thank you.</button></a> "; sg_div.id = "sg-popup"; sg_div.style.position = "absolute"; 
sg_div.style.width = "350px"; sg_div.style.top = "600px"; sg_div.style.left = "400px"; sg_div.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff"; 
sg_div.style.borderColor = "#888888"; sg_div.style.borderStyle = "double"; sg_div.style.padding = "10px"; 
sg_div.style.fontSize = "16px"; document.body.appendChild(sg_div);</script>
```

Comment: Can you format your code to make it readable?  I would think properly formatting your code may go a long way in helping you find your problem. At a glance I already notice some problems with escaping quotes. Also what specific problem are you having in making the div disappear?

Comment: Please post the HTML part where sg-popup is declared

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask\" onclick=\"window.open(this.href,'_self');window.open('#','_blank');\"><button>Yes</button></a>
```

should be

```
<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('sg-popup').style.display = 'none';window.open(this.href,'_self');window.open('#','_blank');\"><button>Yes</button></a>
```

You call document.getElementById('sg-popup').style.display = 'none' on the click event of your 'No' anchor but not on the yes.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you didn't escape the quote at the end of your  tag's href.
`href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"` -->
`href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask\"`

Next, the onclick function that hides sg-popup is only on the anchor tag that wraps your "No" button. If you'd like the same functionality on the "yes" button, you'll have to add `document.getElementById('sg-popup').style.display = 'none';` to the onclick attribute of the anchor tag that wraps your "Yes" button.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have not added any logic for onclick on "Yes" like you have for "No".  I have shown an example of how you can do this (also giving a function for hiding to reduce duplicate code.  I have also made change to significantly increase the readability of your code and fix quote escape problems you have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
var sg_div = document.createElement("div");
sg_div.innerHTML = '<h2>Welcome!</h2>Your opinion is important to us.' +
    ' After your visit, would you be willing to answer a few questions?' +
    '<p><center>' + 
    '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"' +
    ' onclick="hideById(\'sg-popup\');window.open(this.href,\'_self\');' +
    'window.open(\'#\',\'_blank\');">' +
    '<button>Yes</button></a>' +
    '&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
    '<a href="#" onclick="hideById(\'sg-popup\');return false;">' +
    '<button>No, thank you.</button></a>';
sg_div.id = "sg-popup";
sg_div.style.position = "absolute"; 
sg_div.style.width = "350px";
sg_div.style.top = "600px";
sg_div.style.left = "400px";
sg_div.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff"; 
sg_div.style.borderColor = "#888888";
sg_div.style.borderStyle = "double";
sg_div.style.padding = "10px"; 
sg_div.style.fontSize = "16px";
// new function to hide an element given id
document.body.appendChild(sg_div);
function hideById(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}    
</script>
```

It also looks like you need to close the `<p>` tag that you create (I did not show this change as I was not sure whether you may be needing to comply to some ancient HTML standard.